# Subsetting dataframe based on values in a different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df1`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                    'date':    [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                    'str':     ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
```

I want to extract the rows of `df1`, where `id` and `date` have the same value as `id` and `date` in this `labels`-dataframe:

```
labels = pd.DataFrame({'id':   [1, 3, 5, 4], 
                    'date':    [4, 6, 8, 11]})
```

In other words, the output should be:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':      [1, 3, 5], 
                    'date':    [4, 6, 8],
                    'str':     ['a', 'c', 'e']})
```

Comment: It seems need `print (pd.merge(df1, labels))`, it is dupe :(

Comment: @jezrael or written as `df1.merge(labels)`...

Comment: Thanks guys. Please add a reply, so I can accept answers

Comment: @N08 - You are welcome! I really like create answer, but already question answered, so was linked solution.